# Summing a numpy array based on a multi-labeled mask

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have an array:

```
x = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
              [3, 4, 5],
              [6, 7, 8]])
```

And a multi-labeled mask:

```
labels = np.array([[0, 0, 2],
                   [1, 1, 2],
                   [1, 1, 2]])
```

My goal is to sum the entries of `x` together, grouped by `labels`. For example:

```
n_labels = np.max(labels) + 1
out = np.empty(n_labels)
for label in range(n_labels):
    mask = labels == label
    out[label] = np.sum(x[mask])

>>> out
np.array([1, 20, 15])
```

However, as `x` and `n_labels` become large, I see this being inefficient. Each iteration, you are only summing together a small fraction of the number of entries of `x`, but still recompute the mask over all of `labels` (in the expression `labels == label`) and subsequently index over all of `x` (in the expression `x[mask]`). Is there a more efficient way to do this as `x` and `n_labels` grow large?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html#numpy-bincount) with weights:

```
np.bincount(labels.ravel(), weights=x.ravel())
```

out:

```
array([ 1., 20., 15.])
```

Comment: Well, that puts a damper on my over-engineered answer. I had no idea about the second argument to `bincount` until just now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have a reason to operate on 2D arrays, so ravel them first:

```
labels = labels.ravel()
x = x.ravel()
```

If your labels are already indices, you can use `np.argsort` along with `np.diff` and `np.add.reduceat`:

```
index = labels.argsort()
splits = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(labels[index])) + 1]
result = np.add.reduceat(x[index], splits)
```

`labels[index]` is the sorted index. Whenever that changes, you enter a new group, and the `diff` is nonzero. That's what `np.flatnonzero(np.diff(labels[index]))` finds for you. Since `reduceat` takes the stop index past the end of the run, you need to add one. `np.r_` allows you to prepend zero easily to a 1D array, which is necessary for `reduceat` to regard t, and also prepend zero., and also prepend zero.he first run (the last is always automatic).

Before you run `reduceat`, you need to order `x` into the runs defined by `labels`, which is what `x[index]` does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2D arrays with another slow and over-engineered approach using `np.add.at`

```
sums = np.zeros(labels.max()+1, x.dtype)
np.add.at(sums, labels, x)
sums
```

Output

```
array([ 1, 20, 15])
```